# What is the difference between Singleton Design Pattern and Singleton Object In Java?

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton, singleton-methods

This was the question that was asked to me recently in an interview. 
According to me, it is through singleton pattern we can instantiate singleton objects. But, I would like to know whether I am right or not.

Comment: You use a dress (design) pattern to make a dress. The object is the dress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right,
A Singleton Design Pattern is used to instantiate a Singleton Object:

> SingleObject class provides a static method to get its static instance
>   to outside world. SingletonPatternDemo, our demo class will use
>   SingleObject class to get a SingleObject object. [source](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/singleton_pattern.htm)

[image]

The code would look like this:

```
public class SingleObject {

    //create an object of SingleObject
    private static SingleObject instance = new SingleObject();

    //make the constructor private so that this class cannot be
    //instantiated
    private SingleObject() {
    }

    //Get the only object available
    public static SingleObject getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public void showMessage() {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

To call the SingleObject class:

```
public class SingletonPatternDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //illegal construct
        //Compile Time Error: The constructor SingleObject() is not visible
        //SingleObject object = new SingleObject();

        //Get the only object available
        SingleObject object = SingleObject.getInstance();

        //show the message
        object.showMessage();
    }
}
```

So, the Singleton Design Pattern describes how to use a Singleton Object. [WikiLink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)

Please bear in mind that Singletons are, in fact, global variables in disguise. **Thus Singletons are considered to be deprecated.**

Comment: Thankyou.! Next time I'll be this elaborate as well.

Answer (score 1):

Singleton Pattern is a map of a route. Singleton Object is actually going through that route.

And you can drive, walk, and run through that route. If you drive, you can use car, truck (or) any other means.

Same way Single Pattern is a way (or) method of doing something. You can use any language, computer (or) platform to actually implement that Singleton Object.

Comment: Well. This is a nice way to explain as well. THANKYOU.

Answer (score 0):

[Singleton_design_pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)  is a design pattern that restricts the instantiation of a class to one object. This is useful when exactly one object is needed to coordinate actions across the system.

Singleton object is a single object, which has been created by implementing Singleton approach.

To achieve this ( ***TRUE Singleton***) ,

1. Make sure that your class is `final`.  Others can't sub-class it and create one more instance
2. Make your singleton object as  `private static final`
3. Provide  `private` constructor and public `getInstance()` method.
4. Make sure that this Singleton class is loaded by one `ClassLoader` only
5. override `readResolve()` method and return same instance.

Refer to this SE question too for efficient implementation of `Singleton`.

[What is an efficient way to implement a singleton pattern in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70689/what-is-an-efficient-way-to-implement-a-singleton-pattern-in-java)